# Power Series: Derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, power-series, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider a series:
$$|t|\leq R:\quad\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k t^k\quad(A_k\in E)$$

Is there an **elegant** proof of:
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k t^k\right)'=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k kt^{k-1}$$

Already, the radii of convergence agree:
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{(k+1)A_{k+1}}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{kA_k}$$

Moreover, the series converge uniformly on inner disks as:
$$\|\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty A_kt^k\|\leq\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\|A_k\|\cdot|t|^k\leq\sum_{k=K+1}^\infty\|A_k\|\cdot r^k\to0\quad(r<R)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F : \Omega\rightarrow E$ is a vector function on an open domain in $\mathbb{C}$ into a Banach space $E$, then $F$ is holomorphic iff it is weakly holomorphic. In that case $(x^{\star}\circ F)'(\lambda)= x^{\star}\circ F'(\lambda)$ for all $x^{\star}\in E^{\star}$.

Your power series is weakly holomorphic within the radius of convergence, with
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x^{\star}\circ\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{k}A_{k}\right)' 
   & =\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{k}x^{\star}(A_{k})\right)' \\
   & =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\lambda^{k-1}x^{\star}(A_{k}) \\
   & = x^{\star}\circ\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\lambda^{k-1}A_{k}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah right one needs weakly implies strongly here.

Comment: @Freeze_S : If $F$ is an operator function on the open region $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$ with values in $\mathcal{L}(X)$ for a Banach space $X$, then $F$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ iff $x^{\star}(F(\lambda)x)$ is holomorphic for all $x \in X$ and $x^{\star}\in X^{\star}$. In that case $[x^{\star}(F(\lambda)x)]'=x^{\star}(F'(\lambda)x)$. That bootstrapping really makes verifications easier, especially when you combine with Morera's theorem.

Comment: By the way, do you remember that lemma on identifying elements of the double dual of nonreflexive but separable Banach spaces for weak integration? It turns out that the standard example itself on C*-algebras is already nonseparable. :/

Comment: @Freeze_S : Bochner requires values in a separable subspace, a situation to which the double dual argument applies by restriction. So, even in that case, Bochner is subsumed. Riemann-Stieltjes still works nicely, though without requiring separable subspace.

Comment: It was not about Bochner but Pettis (weak) - Bochner is not as interesting for spectral representations especially since spectral measures may have nonseparable range etc.

Comment: @Freeze_S : I was just making the observation that Pettis should probably be preferred over Bochner in Functional Analysis. For a while you were drawn to Bochner, and I'm intent on steering you away. :) And, at the same time, I also want to promote classical integrals where possible such as Riemann-Stieltjes where Pettis still works even when Bochner will not.

Comment: @Freeze_S : By the way, you don't need anything more than the classical Riemann-Stieltjes integral to do spectral theory for densely-defined selfadjoint linear operators on a Hilbert space. You can prove the spectral theorem in that context, and define the spectral measure in terms of a Riemann-Stieljes integral. That makes the theorem far more accessible to Physicists and Engineers, many of whom are already familiar with CDF and integrals $\int f(t)dP(t)$.

Comment: I know you're trying to steer my away from Bochner - weak integrals are nice. ;) Also I really don't like Stiltje's integrals wether Riemann-Stiltjes or Lebesgue-Stiltjes - for me they are just a rather technical way of dealing with induced measures. But at least they are far more accessible for people who are familiar with Riemann. Yep, right..

Answer (score 1):

If you know the result in the scalar case you can use *Hahn-Banach* to extend to the Banach case.

Comment: Nice very strategic ;)